# Ruby on Rails - Carrierwave not saving file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rails-api

I am trying to upload an image using `carrierwave` to save it, at present the paramaters sent only save 'null' to the associated rows, any insight would be appricated:

I'm using the `rails-api` (https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api)

```
#controller
def create
  @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)

  if @picture.save
    render json: @picture, status: :created, location: @picture
  else
    render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :image_url, ImageUploader
end

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

schema

```
create_table "pictures", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "image_url"
  t.integer  "imageable_id"
  t.string   "imageable_type"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

console output

```
Started POST "/pictures" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-01 23:44:47 +0100
Processing by PicturesController#create as */*
Parameters: {"test.jpg"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x2591868 @tempfile=#    <File:C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20140901-5044-1eui2xj>,      @original_filename="test.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"
test.jpg\"; filename=\"test.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}
←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mbegin transaction←[0m
←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "pictures" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-09-01 22:44:47.289649"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-01 22:44:47.289649"]]
←[1m←[36m (509.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mcommit transaction←[0m
Completed 201 Created in 514ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 510.0ms)
```

the above `POST` does not send the imageable_id or type however adding those attributes to the post does not fix the issue.

Edit: adding the following to the controller allows it save other fields but carrierwave still not saving the iamge address

```
def picture_params
  params.require(:picture).permit(:imageable_id, :imageable_type, :image_url)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out: I was using POSTMAN, and needed to list headers as `picture[image_url]`, not just by name.